# junit test class always be one to one with the classes of a program

Tags: junit

I have a implementation class which fetches items from dynamo db and the dynamo table has S3 url as one of its column value. The implementation class call this helper to get the content from S3.

Should we write junits for the individual files or in this cases junit for implementation class would be sufficient allowing impl class to call helper class and mocked the call to S3 ?

Comment: We won't decide how much you should test. That's up to you and your team.

Comment: In general, each class in a program requires a one-one junit class ?

Comment: There is no requirement. You can choose to not test anything, you can choose to test some classes, you can choose to have one test class per production class, or you can choose to have several test classes per class.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you're going to cover with your tests.

If the utility class is also your implementation, go cover it with an individual test.
If it is provided by some external library, testing should occur within the project of this library.